# How do I create a ListBox in ASP.NET MVC with single selection mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I create a ListBox in ASP.NET MVC with single selection mode?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402958/how-to-disable-the-multiple-selection-from-the-list-box-using-jquery-or-javascr

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for a select box visually like the ListBox, meaning with multiple rows displayed, but functionally like the DropDownList (allowing for only one selection).

It looks like there is not a particularly easy way to pull this off using ListBox. I'd suggest using Html.DropdownList, similar to this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("list1", 
    new Dictionary<string, object> {{"size", "5"}} ) %>
```

The size attribute will give the select box the look of a ListBox. Also, you will need to change your ViewData item from MultiSelectList to SelectList.

Comment: BTW the html spec says to use SIZE instead of ROWS. Maybe they both work I'm not sure.

Comment: I think it needs to be new {size = 5}

Comment: you are right. brain lapse -- kept thinking it was rows, looked it up as size, and wrote rows anyway. i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

MVC5.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("PropertyID", null, htmlAttributes: new {size=5, @class="form-control" })
```

Controller

```
ViewBag.PropertyID = new SelectList(db.EntityItems);
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').removeAttr('multiple');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following  Code Works for me,

<%=Html.DropDownList("list1", lstItem, new {@size = 5})%>
  where lstItem represents the List of SelectListItem

Answer (score -2):

the below should do it: The object is translated in a list of attributes for the select element.

Html.DropDownList("list1", new Object {@rows = 5, @multiple = false} )

Comment: Even when you set multiple = false it still ends up as <select multiple>... in the resulting HTML.