# how to disable the multiple selection from the list box using jquery? or javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a list box in my page..

```
<td><%=Html.ListBox("listServiceTypes", Model.ServiceTypeListAll, new { style = "width: 500px;height:200px;" })%>
```

I need to disabled selecting multiple items from the list box? I am doing something like selecting one item and click delete button my page its delting one item from list box.. but If I select multple Items its throwing an error message/.?

Can any body help me out how to deactive or disable multiple items from list box

Comment: does this ASP generate a `<select multiple>...` if so, just call `$('#mySelect').removeAttr('multiple');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *could* do that with the following jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("select[name='listServiceTypes']").removeAttr('multiple');
});
```

However, it would be much better to do it at the server side. Rather than using `Html.ListBox`, it would be better to use `Html.DropDownList`:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("listServiceTypes", 
                Model.ServiceTypeListAll, 
                new { style = "width: 500px;height:200px", size=4 }); %>
```

This removes the need from having to do any jQuery/JavaScript to remove the `multiple` attribute as it produces pretty much the same HTML but without the `multiple` attribute. Having a value for `size` that is greater than 1 tells the browser to display it as a multi-line list box.

Answer (score 3):

This script will turn off multiple selection for all select controls on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').removeAttr('multiple');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get a listbox with single select and not a dropdown list. This got me exactly that. Basically get the ListBoxFor added with size > 1 and then remove multiselect using jQuery.

JS part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.NoMultiSelect').removeAttr('multiple');
        });
    });
</script>
```

html part:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.SelectedItems, Model.AllItems, new {  @class = "NoMultiSelect form-control", size = 4, style = "width: 250px; height: 300px;" })
```