# Getting error at time of binding ListBoxFor control in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I am changing the `"model => model.id"` to `"model => model.Supplierid"` i am getting below error

> "The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when
>   multiple selection is allowed."

please have look on below code

// this my model class

```
public class clslistbox{
public int id { get; set; }
public int Supplierid { get; set; }
public List<SuppDocuments> lstDocImgs { get; set; }

public class SuppDocuments
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int documentid { get; set; }
}
public List<SuppDocuments> listDocImages()
{
    List<SuppDocuments> _lst = new List<SuppDocuments>();
    SuppDocuments _supp = new SuppDocuments();
    _supp.Title = "title";
    _supp.documentid = 1;
    _lst.Add(_supp);
    return _lst;
} 
}
```

// this my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddEditSupplier(int id)
    {

        clslistbox _lst = new clslistbox();
        _lst.lstDocImgs= _lst.listDocImages();
        return View(_lst);
    }
```

// this is view where i am binding listboxfor

```
@model clslistbox
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEditSupplier", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.id, new SelectList(Model.lstDocImgs, "documentid", "title"))
}
```

Can anyone see the reason for it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the changing of the property in the expression here is a red-herring - it won't work in either case.

***Update***

However, see at the end of my answer for some probably needlessly detailed exposition on why you didn't get an error first-time round.

***End Update***

You're using `ListBoxFor` - which is used to provide users with multiple selection capabilities - but you're trying to bind that to an `int` property - which cannot support multiple selection. (It needs to be an `IEnumerable<T>` at least to be able to bind a list box to it by default in MVC)

I think you mean to be using `DropDownListFor` - i.e. to display a list of items from which only one can be selected?

If you're actually looking for single-selection semantics in a listbox, that's trickier to do in MVC because it's Html helpers are geared entirely around listboxes being for multiple selection.  Someone else on SO has asked a question about how to get a dropdown to look like a list box: [How do I create a ListBox in ASP.NET MVC with single selection mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351483/how-do-i-create-a-listbox-in-asp-net-mvc-with-single-selection-mode).

Or you could generate the HTML for such a listbox yourself.

***(Update) - Potentially needlessly detailed exposition(!)***

The reason you don't get an exception first time round is probably because there was no value for `id` in `ModelState` when the HTML was generated.  Here's the reflected MVC source (from `SelectExtensions.SelectInternal`) that's of interest (the `GetSelectListWithDefaultValue` call at the end is the source of your exception):

```
object obj = 
  allowMultiple ? htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullHtmlFieldName, typeof(string[])) : 
    htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullHtmlFieldName, typeof(string));
if (!flag && obj == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
  obj = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(name);
}
if (obj != null)
{
  selectList = 
    SelectExtensions.GetSelectListWithDefaultValue(selectList, obj, allowMultiple);
}
```

Note first that the control variable `allowMultiple` is true in your case, because you've called `ListBoxFor`.  `selectList` is the `SelectList` you create and pass as the second parameter.  One of the things that MVC (unfortunately in some cases) does is to use `ModelState` to modify the select list you pass when re-displaying a view in order to ensure that values which were set in `ModelState` via a POST are re-selected when the view is reloaded (this is useful when page validation fails because you won't copy the values to your underlying model from `ModelState`, but the page should still show those values as being selected).

So as you can see on the first line, the model's current value for the expression/field you pass is fished out of model state; either as a string array or as a string.  If that fails (returns `null`)then it makes another go to execute the expression (or similar) to grab the model value.  If it gets a non-null value from there, it calls `SelectExtensions.GetSelectListWithDefaultValue`.

As I say - what you're trying to do will ultimately not work in either the case of `Id` or `SupplierId` (because they would need to be `IEnumerable`) **but** I believe this `ModelState`->`Eval` process is yielding a null value when you use `Id`, so the process of getting an 'adjusted' `SelectList` is skipped - so the exception doesn't get raised.  The same is not true when you use `SupplierId` because I'll wager that there's either a value in `ModelState` at that point, or the `ViewData.Eval` successfully gets an integer value.

*Not throwing an exception* is **not** the same as ***working***!.

***End update***

Comment: thanks, do you know what the reason that it's not giving error for model.id

Comment: The answer seems correct (and logical), but why did "something" work with `model => model.id` then ? Any idea ?

Comment: Yeah - that 'something' is important.  Does 'something' simply mean no exception?  If so, that's not enough for it to class as 'working'.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus : Updated answer with explanation

Comment: Thx for explanation, I also noticed (tested) that both solutions were not "working", but couldn't get the why they "didn't work the same way" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your property from int to int[]

```
 public class SuppDocuments
 {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int documentid { get; set; }
 }
```

Assuming above is the class used for binding the model , try changing the documentid property as below

```
 public class SuppDocuments
 {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int[] documentid { get; set; }
 }
```